# Why does normality imply that a countable base $B$ contains at least one set $U$ whose closure is a subset of another set $V \in B$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, hausdorff-spaces

I'm reading Aliprantis and Border's excellent text, *Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide* (PDF available at link, assuming I've done this properly), and I've reached an impasse in the proof of the Urysohn Metrization theorem (3.40, p. 91).

The premises give that $X$ is Hausdorff, and additionally under equivalent statement 3 that $X$ is regular and second countable, so it has a countable base $B$. These conditions also imply by a preceding theorem (2.49, p. 46) that $X$ is normal. For the purposes of the remainder of the proof (which is to show that $X$ can be embedded in the Hilbert cube given regularity and second countability), the authors construct a set $C$ of pairs of nested elements of $B$ such that $C = \{(U,V):\bar{U}\subset V \ \& \ U,V \in B\}$.
Then they say, "The normality of $X$ implies that $C$ is nonempty." I've spent considerable time and effort trying to verify this myself, and haven't been able to figure out. It's definitely not a preceding result in this textbook (which is generally very self-contained). And although I've looked around here on Mathoverflow, my topological background might be too weak to see how this is an easy corollary of another theorem.

Comment: There must be more conditions than you've stated here.  For example, the discrete space on a countable set X has a countable basis (consisting of the (clopen) singleton sets), but no set A in that basis is a proper subset of any set B in the basis.  Note that the discrete topology is Hausdorff and normal.

Comment: @Apollo I suppose the inclusion is not meant to be strict, so that if $U$ is clopen as in your example you can take $V=U$

Comment: @alessandro-codenotti - That makes sense, though I would not call it a "proper" subset.  (It may be that the text does not require that and was just assumed by the OP, forgetting about the possibility of clopen sets.)

Comment: Also I think this can be shown by an argument similar to the one used to show that a regular space has a local basis of closed sets at every point with a couple extra steps

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I think $V=U$ is the right solution for the countable case. I had wondered about that and checked the notational conventions as addressed in the book as far as proper subsets, but I wasn't confident of my reasoning, and the character limits prevented me from including this point in the question.

Comment: With that in mind I've removed "proper" from the question. I think this can be considered answered now.

Comment: Was there meant to be a link where you say "PDF available at link"?  The DOI is <https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-03004-2>, if that's what you wanted.  (By the way, I notice you rightly edited out the `\[ \]`, since the semantically correct way of doing it is not supported by MathJax; but, if you want a displayed environment, then the old-style `$$ $$` works just fine.)

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm not particularly familiar with this syntax, yet. Thanks.